# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection') I'm not sure why I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql, mern

I have been working on a to do list style application and I am receiving the above error and am not sure why, I have spent a few days studying the problem but have not yet found a solution anywhere. Below is my index.js file for the application. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I received this error in the apollo sandbox, if that is any help.

```
 const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
                const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
                const dotenv = require('dotenv');
                const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
                dotenv.config();
                
                const { DB_URI, DB_NAME } = process.env;
                
            
                const typeDefs = gql`
                type Query {
                    myTaskList: [TaskList!]!
                }
            
                type Mutation {
                    signUp(input: SignUpInput): AuthUser!
                    signIn(input: SignUpInput): AuthUser!
                }
            
                input SignUpInput {
                    email: String!
                    password: String!
                    name: String!
                    avatar: String
                }
            
                input SingInInput {
                    email: String!
                    password: String!
                }
            
                type AuthUser {
                    user: User!
                    token: String!
                }
            
                type User {
                    id: ID!
                    name: String!
                    email: String!
                    avatar: String
                }
            
                type TaskList {
                    id: ID! 
                    createdAt: String!
                    title: String!
                    progress: Float!
            
                    users: [User!]!
                    todos: [ToDo!]!
                }
            
                type ToDo {
                    id: ID! 
                    content: String!
                    isCompleted: Boolean!
            
                    #taskListId: ID!
                    taskList: TaskList
                }
            `;
        
        
            const resolvers = {
            Query: {
                myTaskList: () => []
            },
        
            Mutation: {
                signUp: async (_,{input}, {db}) => {
                    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(input.password);
                    // console.log(hashedPassword);
                    const newUser = {
                        ...input,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                    }
                    //save to database
                    const result = await db.collection('Users').insert(newUser);
                    // console.log(resolvers);
                    const user = result.ops[0]
                    return {
                        user,
                        token: 'token'
                    }
                },
        
                signIn: () => {
        
                },
            },
        };
        
        
        // console.log(DB_URI);
        const start = async () => {
            const client = new MongoClient(DB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
            await client.connect();
            const db = client.db(DB_NAME);
        
        
            const context = {
                db,
            }
        
    
        const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
    
        server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
        console.log(` server ready at ${url}`);
    });
    };

start();
```

Comment: It means `db` is undefined when you do `await db.collection('Users').insert(newUser);`